# Beautiful Soup crashes upon special chars like "&quot;" and "&lt;"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an atom based RSS feed using beautiful soup, but it's proving difficult.  Capturing the data goes just fine until an `<item>` comes up that breaks the code and crashes the script.  Such `<item>`s consistently have tags (firefox marks them in orange) like "& lt;" or "& quot;", while s without them work fine.  I've tried a bunch of stuff like BeautifulStoneSoup, stripping special chars with regex, and setting the "xml" argument, but nothing works and often they just throw a warning about being deprecated in BS4.

Why do these characters appear and how can I deal with them effectively?

Here's a page I'm trying to scrape: 
http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss

And here's my code:

```
news_url = "http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss" # Toronto Star RSS Feed

try:    
    news_rss = urllib2.urlopen(news_url)
    news = news_rss.read()
    news_rss.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(news)
except:
    return "error"

titles = soup.findAll('title')
links = soup.findAll('link')

for link in links:
    link = link.contents    # I want the url without the <link> tags

news_stuff = []
for item in titles:
    if item.text == "TORONTO STAR | NEWS | GTA":    # These have <title> tags and I don't want them; just skip 'em.
        pass
    else:
        news_stuff.append((item.text, links[i]))    # Here's a news story.  Grab it.

i = 0
for thing in news_stuff:
    print '<a href="' 
    print thing[1]
    print '"target="_blank">' 
    print thing[0]
    print '</a><br/>'
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which problem you are talking about, but I got this error while running you code:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To fix it I just added encoding:

```
for thing in news_stuff:
    print '<a href="' 
    print thing[1]
    print '"target="_blank">' 
    print thing[0].encode("utf-8")
    print '</a><br/>'
    i += 1
```

After that script executes without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried and it did not crash.

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
import MySQLdb
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
news_url = "http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss" # Toronto Star RSS Feed

news_rss = urllib2.urlopen(news_url)
news = news_rss.read()
news_rss.close()
soup = Soup(news)

titles = soup.findAll('title')
links = soup.findAll('link')

for link in links:
    link = link.contents    # I want the url without the <link> tags
i=0
news_stuff = []
for item in titles:
    if item.text == "TORONTO STAR | NEWS | GTA":    # These have <title> tags and I don't want them; just skip 'em.
        pass
    else:
        news_stuff.append((item.text, links[i]))    # Here's a news story.  Grab it.

i = 0
for thing in news_stuff:
    print '<a href="' 
    print thing[1]
    print '"target="_blank">' 
    print thing[0]
    print '</a><br/>'
    i += 1
```

and here is what I am getting as the output

```
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
TTC argues for return of special constables
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Health information of 18,000 people stolen in Peel Region
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Fire closes Bathurst St. south of Dupont
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Empty tanker train cars derail in Brampton
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Medical illustration studios flourish in Toronto
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
In Texas, Toronto music leaders urge city hall to say ‘yes’
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Making sense of the Sammy Yatim shooting: Fiorito
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Toronto’s chief planner, Jennifer Keesmaat, challenges Mirvish/Gehry scheme: Hume
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Westbound Gardiner lanes reopen after rollover near Spadina
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Daycare Crisis: Halton health complaints show gaps in unlicensed care
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Witness describes shooting details as man confronted police near van
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Muslim AIDS activist honoured for taboo-busting work
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Death to death with dignity: DiManno
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Rockers join forces in Line 9 protest
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Could you eat 10 pizzas in 12 minutes? This guy did
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Former participants speak up about gay healing program
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Freed Canadians Tarek Loubani and John Greyson awaiting papers to come home from Egypt
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Man dies after crash at Finch and Dufferin
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Nuit Blanche lights up Toronto Saturday night
</a><br/>
<a href="
<link>http://www.thestar.com/feeds.articles.news.gta.rss</link>
"target="_blank">
Leafs fans celebrate home opener at Maple Leaf Square
</a><br/>
```